# Code:Blocks c++ precompiled header linker errors

Tags: c++, g++, codeblocks, precompiled-headers

I've just transferred a vc++ project over to code::blocks on linux, using the g++ compiler, as that's the target platform, and it's refusing to compile.

I'm getting errors like:

```
g++: error: inc/BarcodeServer.h.gch/Debug_inc_BarcodeServer_h_gch: No such file or directory
```

Firstly, I don't want to use pre-compiled headers anyway, so I have no idea why it's looking for .gch files. I just want to use standard .h headers.

Secondly, the file names it's looking for seem bizzare, like it's looking for a directory inside a file, though this could just my unfamiliarity with g++.

I'm not really sure what steps I need to take in Code::Blocks to have it simply use the .h files to compile. I've looked around, and in the build options there's a "precompiled header strategy" but none of the options are just "don't use them"

Any help would be appreciated.